# Vigenere cipher 'string index out of range' for decryption

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, vigenere

my Vigenere cipher works perfectly for encryption but I just need to fix this problem for decryption where I am told, after running the program, that the string index is out of range. Could someone please let me know what i need to change it to, I would be extremely grateful if you could.

edit: I have changed the part of the code that was causing the string index problem but now, when processing decryption, the output is a blank line with 'None' beneath it and no error.

edit: ord(_key_text[letters%len(_key_text)]) i needed to replace _key_text with _key_phrase on this side of the equation in decrypt.

```
#encryption
def encrypt():
    crypt = ''
    key_phrase = raw_input("Please enter a key phrase to encrypt by: ")
    key_phrase = key_phrase.upper()
    key_text = raw_input("Please enter a piece of text to encrypt: ")
    key_text = key_text.upper()
    if len(key_text) == 0: 
        print("Key must be of length 1 or more."); exit()
    if not key_text.isalpha() or not key_phrase.isalpha():
        print("Both text and key must be composed of letters only."); exit()
    for letters in range(0, len(key_text)):
        new = ord(key_text[letters]) + ord(key_text[letters%len(key_text)]) - 65
       if new > 90:
            new -= 26
        crypt += chr(new)
    print crypt

#decryption
def decrypt():
    decrypt = ''
    _key_phrase = raw_input("Please enter a key phrase to encrypt by: ")
    _key_phrase = _key_phrase.upper()
    _key_text = raw_input("Please enter a piece of text to encrypt: ")
    _key_text = _key_text.upper()
    if len(_key_text) == 0: 
        print("Key must be of length 1 or more."); exit()
    if not _key_text.isalpha() or not _key_phrase.isalpha():
        print("Both text and key must be composed of letters only."); exit()
    for letters in range(0, len(_key_text)):
        new = ord(_key_text[letters]) - ord(_key_text[letters%len(_key_text)]) + 65
        if new < 65:
            new += 26
        decrypt == chr(new)
    print decrypt

#asking the user to enter a or b for en/decryption and whether they wish to continue
choice = raw_input("Please enter either 'a' for encryption or 'b' for decryption: ")
if choice == 'a':
    print encrypt()
else:
    print decrypt()
```

Comment: posting the traceback would be helpful

Comment: BTW there is no need to set explicitly start value in `range()` to 0. 0 is the default value and you can omit it in this case.

Comment: Further cosiderations: 1. there must no be `print` in `print encrypt()` and `print decrypt()`. 2. You ask to enter encrypt key and text in `decrypt` function. 3. You functions encrypt and decrypt text only without spaces. 4. Encrypted text is SHORTER than the original text. I dont think it is correct with Vigenere cypher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key text is longer than key phrase  you'll get an invalid index here :
`new = ord(_key_phrase[letters]) - ord(_key_text[letters%len(_key_text)])`
when `letters` becomes  greater than `len(_key_text)`

You have `key_text` on both places in `encryption` and `key text` and `key phrase` in decryption so you have to change one variable here.

Comment: thank you that helps with the string index but now my result is a blank line followed by 'none'. do you know why that may be?

Comment: `None` is the return value of you `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions. You print it in your `print`-statements. And you get a blank line because your algorith is not correct, I think.

Comment: ord(_key_text[letters%len(_key_text)])  i needed to replace _key_text with _key_phrase on this side of the equation. thank you for your help.