# What does "string index out of range" mean in this Vigenere cipher?

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

```
#Vigenere Cipher
EncryptedMessage=""
Mode=""
Keywordcount = 0 #sets everything to 0
KeywordTwocount = 0

while Mode != "encrypt" and Mode != "decrypt":
    Mode = input('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
    Mode = Mode.lower()

if Mode == "encrypt":
    Message=input('Please eneter the message you wish to encrypt: ')
    Keyword=input('Please enter the keyword you want to use:')
    KeywordTwo = input(' Please enter second keyword you want to use:') 
    Keywordlength = len(Keyword)
    KeywordTwolength = len(KeywordTwo)

    for i in range(0, len(Message)):
        Messageencrypt = Message[i]
        Keywordencrypt = Keyword[Keywordcount]
        KeywordTwoencrypt= KeywordTwo[KeywordTwocount]
        if Messageencrypt.isalpha():
            if Messageencrypt.isupper():
                Messageencrypt = ord(Messageencrypt)
                Keywordencrypt = Keywordencrypt.upper()
                Keywordencrypt = ord(Keywordencrypt) - 64
                KeywordTwoencrypt = KeywordTwoencrypt.upper()
                KeywordTwoencrypt = ord(Keyword2encrypt) - 64
                FirstCodedMessage = Messageencrypt + Keywordencrypt
                FinalCodedMessage = FirstCodedMessage + Keyword2encrypt
                if FinalCodedMessage > 90:
                    FinalCodedMessage = FinalCodedMessage - 26
                Encryptedletter = chr(FinalCodedMessage)
            elif Messageencrypt.islower():
                Messageencrypt = ord(Messageencrypt)
                Keywordencrypt = Keywordencrypt.upper()
                Keywordencrypt = ord(Keywordencrypt) - 64
                KeywordTwoencrypt = KeywordTwoencrypt.upper()
                KeywordTwoencrypt = ord(KeywordTwoencrypt) - 64
                FinalCodedMessage = Messageencrypt + Keywordencrypt
                if FinalCodedMessage > 122:
                    FinalCodedMessage = FinalCodedMessage - 26
            Encryptedletter = chr(FinalCodedMessage)
        else:
            Encryptedletter = Messageencrypt
        EncryptedMessage = EncryptedMessage + Encryptedletter
        Keywordcount = Keywordcount + 1
        if Keywordcount >= Keywordlength:
            Keywordcount = 0
        KeywordTwocount = KeywordTwocount + 1
        if KeywordTwocount >= Keywordlength:
            KeywordTwocount = 0
    print(EncryptedMessage)
```

What does

```
KeywordTwoencrypt= KeywordTwo[KeywordTwocount]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

mean? [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JGXg.png)

Also how would I save this encrypted message as a txt file? [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH7Xt.png)

Comment: It's time to learn about functions which encapsulate a part of the code in a callable fashion.

Comment: i dont know what that means im a beginner at python  soooooooo............

Comment: I understood that you're a beginner. That's why I suggested that you learn about [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) so that you can call the same code with different parameters without copying it around.

Comment: ok, i will comment again if i get stuck

Comment: i managed to d oit but know is says "KeywordTwoencrypt= Keyword2[KeywordTwocount]
NameError: name 'Keyword2' is not defined"

Comment: wrong error pls chech the error in image provided

Comment: Copy the code from http://stackoverflow.com/q/32595168/243712

Comment: i wantto encrypt the message twice and save the encrypted message as a text file

Comment: i would rather want to know how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

`if KeywordTwocount >= Keywordlength:` should be `if KeywordTwocount >= KeywordTwolength:`

If there is an index problem, then you should look closer to all parts of the code that deal with this specific index incrementation/decrementation.

In this specific case, you should see that the index of the second keyword shouldn't have anything to do with the length of the first keyword. So the updating is buggy:

```
if KeywordTwocount >= Keywordlength:
    KeywordTwocount = 0
```

---

This error would have been easily avoidable by defining a function that encrypts a message with one keyword:

```
def vigenere(message, keyword):
    ...
```

And then you can chain those two together:

```
print(vigenere(vigenere(message, keyword1), keyword2))
```

---

Writing to a file is also easy with the built-in functions:

```
with open('ciphertext.txt', 'w') as ct:
    ct.write(EncryptedMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

`KeywordTwo[KeywordTwoCount] IndexError: string index out of range` means that the index (`KeywordTwoCount`) is greater than the length of the string you're indexing in to `KeywordTwo`.

Comment: im in a rush i dont have time